# How to initialize an Object?

Tags: c#

I have a class like this,

```
public class person
{
 name Name {set; get;}
 string Address {set; get;}
}

public class name
{
  string First {set; get;}
  string Last {set; get;}
}
```

Now when I create the object an try to set the first or last name I get an error. "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

```
person Person = new person();
Person.Name.First = "John";
Person.Name.Last ="Smith";
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not a solution to your problem, but you should follow the guidelines and use Pascal casing for type names. i.e. use Person rather than person.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to initialise the name class instance too

```
person Person = new person();
Person.Name = new name();
Person.Name.First = "A";
```

You could also do this in the constructor of `person` if you wish

```
public class person
    {
        public name Name { set; get; }
        string Address { set; get; }

        public person()
        {
            Name = new name();
        }
    }
```

Or even try

```
person Person = new person { Name = new name { First = "A", Last = "B" } };
```

Answer (score 5):

That is because the Name property is null. You haven't assigned it a value.

Try this:

```
person p = new person();
p.Name = new Name();
p.Name.First = "John";
p.Name.Last = "Smith";
```

Or using object initializer syntax available from C# 3.0 and newer:

```
var p = new person { Name = new name { 
    First = "John", Last = "Smith" } 
};
```

Comment: According to their type names, this should be `person p = new person();`. Not that I agree with their naming convention.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [object initializer](http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/12/04/ObjectInitializationExpressions.aspx). Although  it's very verbose for complex objects in your example you can do

```
new Person { Name = { First = "John", Last = "Smith" } };
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize the `name` property of person. Try:

```
person Person = new person(); 
person.name = new name();
Person.Name.First = "John"; 
Person.Name.Last ="Smith";
```

WHen you define a class or struct, the C# language (and the CLR really) assigns defaults to all fields of the object when it is instantiated. The default are specific to the type of the field, but for references (which `Name` is in your case) the default is `null`. You are responsible for instantiating objects.

An alternative way to handle this situation would be to create a default `name` instance in the constructor of the `person` class; like so:

```
public class person  
{  
  name Name {set; get;}  
  string Address {set; get;}  

  public Person() { Name = new name(); }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the code you want to use, just initialize your `name` object in person's constructor.

On a deeper level, what you're doing wrong is violating the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) by accessing Name's properties outside of the Person class.

Answer (score 0):

Your class needs a [constructor](http://www.csharphelp.com/2007/05/c-constructor/) which will assign values to your properties when **new** is used to create an instance of your class.

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize person and name

```
person Person = new person(); 
person.name = new name();
Person.Name.First = "John"; 
Person.Name.Last ="Smith";
```

Check this [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_conventions_%28programming%29) for an overview on Naming convention.